# How should I resolve this error：TypeError: Canny() takes no arguments

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to python and trying to create an **OpenCV** demo while learning how to use the Canny() function.

This error occurs when I run the program:`TypeError: Canny() takes no arguments`

Here is my complete demo code：

```py
import cv2

# 载入图片
img = cv2.imread("WhiteDolphinPic/WhiteDolphin_1.jpg")
print(img.shape)

# 自定义图片大小
imgResize = cv2.resize(img,(400,300))
print(imgResize.shape)

# 将imgResize设置为灰度图、高斯模糊和边缘检测
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgResize,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(7,7),0)
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray,100,100)

cv2.imshow("ImgResize",imgResize)
cv2.imshow("ImgGray",imgGray)
cv2.imshow("ImgBlur",imgBlur)
cv2.imshow("ImgCanny",imgCanny)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I suspect you need to have two different values. Try making the last value 200.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.  I don't believe the error you showed us came from this code.   Can you show us the whole traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../chapter01.py", line 14, in <module>
    imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray,100,100)
TypeError: Canny() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have two definitions of Canny in cv2 namespace or have multiple opencv packages installed? Is it possible that there's a function without any arguments that is taking precedence over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.According to @Knight Forked's reply, I checked the Settings in the Python interpreter and found that I had used the configuration shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8jjn.png), but the configuration shown in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8kbl.png) worked fine.
Thank you all for your help.